# Исключение System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения, наследование

В Winforms хочу нарисовать поле для игры. Имеется абстрактный класс клетки, от которого наследуются все элементы поля.

Класс Cell

```
public abstract class Cell
    {
        public string Path;
        public Image Image;

        public Cell(string path)
        {
            Path = path;
            Image = new Bitmap(Path);
        }

        public virtual void Draw(Graphics gr, int j, int i, int side, int x, int y)
        {
            gr.DrawImage(this.Image, j * side + x, i * side + y, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(side, side)), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

    }
```

Класс наследник

```
class Empty : Cell
    {
        public Empty() : base($"../../Resources/grass.jpg") { }
    }
```

[image: Ошибка]
Скрин ошибки

Не могу понять, в чём ошибка. Почему "Недопустимый параметр"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public Cell(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path))
            throw Exception("Path to cell image is null or empty.");
        if (!File.Exists(Path))
            throw Exception("File of cell image does not exist: " + Path);
        Image = new Bitmap(Path);
    }
```